# Problems decoding German "Umlaute" of QR-Codes with "pyzbar"

Tags: python, qr-code

I wrote a Python (V3.9.9) program (Windows 10) to decode QR-Codes of type "EPC QR" -> see [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPC-QR-Code)

Everything is working fine, except, if there are German "Umlaute" (ÄÖÜäöü) within the text of the QR-Code. Here is a sample program, to demonstrate/isolate the problem:

```
import cv2 # Read image / camera/video input
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

img = cv2.imread ("GiroCodeUmlaute.PNG")

print (decode (img))
               
for code in decode (img):
    print (code.type)
    print (code.data.decode ("UTF-8"))
```

And here is the QR-Code for testing:
[GiroCodeUmlaute.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw2JN.png) -> [see QR-Code generator](https://barcode.tec-it.com/de/EPCQRCode)

The 6th line of the encoded QR-Code text contains "**Ä**rzte ohne Grenzen".
But when it's decoded with "UTF-8" (which is the correct character set), then "**ﾃв**zte ohne Grenzen" is displayed.

I think, also the decoded read hex data are looking a bit strange:

> [Decoded(data=b'BCD\n002\n1\nSCT\nRLNWATWW\n\xef\xbe\x83\xd0\xb2zte ohne Grenzen...

From where are the 4(!) hex bytes coming? **\xef\xbe\x83\xd0\xb2**zte
Where is the **'r'** of the original text?

The same problem occurs, if this test-program is running under a Raspberry computer.
If this sample QR-Code is scanned by an android mobile app, the "Umlaut" is correct displayed.
From my point of view it looks like a problem of the "pyzbar" module. But maybe I'm doing something wrong?
Every help and tip is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: That byte sequence doesn't look like correct UTF-8. You might try other [encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings), but it's likely a bug in that pyzbar library. You may also try [pyzbar-x](https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar-x/) instead.

Comment: I would tend to agree with you. Scanning the QR code with the software "BCTester" reveals that the content after "..ATWW" is bytes `0A C3 84 72` which is exactly the string `\nÄr` in UTF8.

Comment: @tromgy: I already used other encodings, but without success. I also tried to find these byte combinations in several coding tables, but didn't get a match.
Using "pyzbar-x" gives the same error/result.

Comment: @MyICQ: Thanks for the hint of the "BcTester" tool. I checked it by myself and it looks really like a pyzbar problem.
I already tried other QR-Code decoder, but these one are not able to detect/decode a QR-Codes of type "EPC QR".

Comment: @canicula the "EPC QR" is an ordinary QR code related to symbology and encoding. The "EPC" part is in the data format only. Like someone stating that a QR containing the text `QR` in front is a special type. It's not.  Just to clarify that encoding and data are two different things. (I work with barcodes and structure daily).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same Problem with Swiss Bill QR-Codes on Linux using the python3-qrtools - guess this module is using the zbar-library as well.
A workaround would be to replace the wrong chars in the decoded string. Depending on the output you get out with `print (code.data.decode ("UTF-8"))` for your Umlaute, I got the following symbols which I need to replace with ä, ö resp. ü:

```
    string = string.replace('瓣', 'ä')
    string = string.replace('繹', 'ö')
    string = string.replace('羹', 'ü')
```

It's not a very elegant solution because it does not deal with all special characters which get wrongly decoded.

As I'm calling the python program from a Pascal/Delphi/lazarus Program, I hope to find an other tool somewhere around which reads QR-codes from the webcam and correctly decode it...